# Does effect of force travel faster than light?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, faster-than-light, causality

Suppose force (sufficient to move a block & imagine it(the block of course) to be extremely long and rigid ) is applied at one end of the block and the Block starts moving.

- Now force must be transmitted through the material of block
- the block is rigid so the other end block moved as soon as force was applied

Doesn't the force appear to transmitted at faster than light speed?

Comment: Concerning faster than light: Are you asking for an answer that uses the model of Newtonian mechanics, or are you looking for a more realistic answer?

Comment: The answers to the linked question are still partly relevant in Newtonian mechanics. But of course in Newtonian mechanics there is no rule that says that things cannot move faster than  the speed of light.